# Ruby Reading and Writing Files

Tags: ruby

I've the following piece of code. For the code to work correctly it should be reading the lines and writing them to the console. I'm currently only getting Error: first line of file is not a number.

Any help possible would be great.

```
def write(aFile, number)

  aFile.puts(number)
  index = 0
  while (index <= number)
   aFile.puts(index)
   index += 1
  end
end


def read(aFile)


  count = aFile.gets
  if (is_numeric?(count))
    count = count.to_i
  else
    count = 0
    puts "Error: first line of file is not a number"
  end

  index = 0
  while (count < index)
    line = aFile.gets
    puts "Line read: " + line
    index += 1
  end
end


def main
  aFile = File.new("mydata.txt", "w") 
  if aFile  
    write(aFile, 10)
    aFile.close
    aFile = File.new("mydata.txt", "r") 
    read(aFile)
    aFile.close
  else
    puts "Unable to open file to write or read!"
  end
end

def is_numeric?(obj)
  if /[^0-9]/.match(obj) == nil
    true
  end
  false
end

main
```

Comment: Check cause I posted in answer, I will update to give you result as per your expected output.

Comment: Hint: what does the `s` in `gets` stand for? Second hint: it does not stand for "number"!

Comment: `is_numeric?` always returns `false`. `"is_numeric?"` is not a good choice for the name of this method as you are simply testing whether the string contains a digit (for which the regex could be `/\d/`). Assuming you want the string to represent a non-negative integer you could write: `def nni?(str) str.match?(/\A\d+\z/) end`.

Answer (score 1):

Please check following,

```
count = aFile.gets
if (is_numeric?(count))
  count = count.to_i
else
  count = 0
  puts "Error: first line of file is not a number"
end
```

When you read file lines, you always read lines in text/string (even numbers inside files). So you are always in else block.